TypeError: Updater.__init__( telegram bot
I have an error in the code below and I cannot solve it. Can you help me?
The latest version of the telegram bot is installed
I couldn't find how to solve it yet
error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx", line 15, in <module>
    updater = Updater(bot=bot)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'

I have pip install telegram bot last version
